# Why would I include iostream and ostream separately?

Tags: c++, iostream

I've noticed that many people include iostream and ostream in C++ programs separately, like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
int main()
{
}
```

Why would anyone do that? Since iostream inherits from ostream, it should include everything in it, right? Is there some obscure reason? What about simple (std::cout) code?

Comment: note: the "duplicate" was later in time than this question, however it has more comprehensive answers so I have put the link that way around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although `stringstream` inherits from `iostream`, it is not declared in the `<iostream>` header.  The `<iostream>` header contains the definition of the `iostream` type along with the famous `cout`, `cerr`, `cin`, and `clog` types, but not other types that are `iostreams` (for example, file streams).  For these, you do need to explicitly `#include` the requisite header files.

**EDIT**: In response to your revised question, I pulled up the C++ spec and interestingly it does *not* say that `<iostream>` has to include either `<ostream>` or `<istream>`.  In fact, it could get away with just including `<iosfwd>`.  Consequently, it's possible to `#include <iostream>` without actually getting a full class definition for either `istream` or `ostream`.  Only explicitly including those headers can guarantee that the *definitions* of those classes, not just the forward-declarations, are visible.

Comment: Sorry, I meant ostream which is what I used in the actual question and text. I have amended the code.

Comment: To whoever downvoted: can you explain what the problem is with this answer?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that it's illegal to use the value of an object of incomplete type, so an `<iostream>` which doesn't include `<ostream>` declares an absolutely useless `std::cout`. I doubt many library implementers ever tried to do that to their customers.

Answer (score 5):

`iostream` explicitly includes `istream` and `ostream` (C++0x requires this, and the gnu libstdc++ version does this), so ostream is technically unnecessary

for future reference:

`fstream` contains the declaration for fstream (file streams),

`sstream` contains the declaration for stringstream (string streams)

`iostream` declares the standard i/o facilities (e.g. cin, cout, ...)

`iosfwd` is the standard header that forward-declares the major types.

Comment: @Foo Bah- Can you confirm that <iostream> includes these two headers?  The spec seems to be mute on this point.

Comment: @templatetypedef gnu makes the claim here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt11ch24.html

Comment: @Foo Bah- This is true for the GNU implementation, but is it guaranteed to be this way?  That is, could someone make a conformant compiler that didn't do it like this?

Comment: @templatetypedef `iostream` declares `cout`, and `cout` is an object of type `ostream`, which is declared in `ostream` header

Comment: @Foo Bah- `<iostream>` actually just contains `extern` declarations for these types, and with the forward declarations in `<iosfwd>` it seems like it could get by without those headers.

Comment: @templatetypedef actually had to dig this out :/  yes according to C++98, you technically could define iostream without istream, but that would involve `<iostream>` including `<iosfwd>`.  C++0x explicitly requires `<iostream>` to include `<istream>` and `<ostream>`.  Technically the best way to be compliant with old and new standards is to have iostream include istream and ostream

Comment: @Foo Bah- Thanks for finding that!  I know this is a minute point, but it actually could influence the way in which I write C++ code.

Comment: @templatetypedef http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf -- page 975

Comment: If `<iostream>` was not guaranteed to define the streams, then the classic `#include <iostream> / int main() { std::cout << "Hello world!\n"; }` is flawed as it needs implementation... bit hard to believe that's true on any real compiler, whether the Standard's explicit or not.

Comment: @Tony <iostream> declares cout.  that wasnt templatetypedef's question.  his question was that the declaration was available in both <ostream> and <iosfwd>