# C++ headers - Why would a program include both iostream and ostream?

Tags: c++

I saw some programs including `<iostream>` and `<ostream>` simultaneously. Why?

Thanks for your kind reply.

Comment: What is the question over here?

Comment: @wwww he had invisible `<words>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<iostream>` is **not** the combination of `<istream>` and `<ostream>`. It merely defines `std::cin`, `std::cout` and related objects. To actually do anything useful with `std::cout`, you still need `<ostream>`. Now, by C++ rules it's possible that some implementations actually do include `<ostream>` in `<iostream>`, but you shouldn't rely on this.

Comment: This is an almost-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930176/why-would-i-include-iostream-and-ostream-separately

Answer (score 2):

Why? Probably because it originally included just `ostream` and someone figured out it had to use input streams as well. Then they just didn't bother to remove the `ostream` include.

Or maybe they actually needed the concrete `cin/cout/cerr` stream objects which are defined in `iostream` separately to the stuff in `istream/ostream`, and they didn't realise that `iostream` pulls in both `istream` and `ostream` before defining those objects.

Without asking the author, it's hard to say, but those are at least two *viable* possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Someone forgot to remove a header probably.  You should always include only what you need in an implementation file but sometimes stuff gets left behind because people are lazy and/or don't know any better.

You should remove the one that is not needed.

Comment: You don't _need_ to remove it since that will have zero effect. `iostream` itself includes `istream` and `ostream` and the standard mandates that implementations must take care of multiple inclusions. My advice would be to leave what isn't broken alone, if only for the sake of not needing an edit in source control. Next time you _have_ to edit the file, think about removing it.

Comment: Bad advice.  Extra, pointless code is confusing.